# Contrasting C# generics with Haskell parameterized types

Tags: c#, generics, haskell, polymorphism, type-systems

Based on some advice I found on StackOverflow, I'm digging into Haskell. I was pleased to see that Haskell's parameterized types behave very much like C# generics. Both languages advise a single letter for the type parameter (usually), and both languages seem to follow a similiar process for substituting an actual type for the type parameter. I grokked the concept pretty quickly because of that.

Which leads to this: what are some ways in which Haskell's parameterized types differ from C# generic types? I know from learning Ruby that you can get into big trouble thinking that a concept you're familiar with from one language is the same in another language you're new to. Usually, the trouble is worse when the features actually *are* very similar ... because they're usually *not* 100% the same. So what are some of the "gotchas" I might get bitten by if I assume I understand parameterized types based on my knowledge of C# generics?

Thanks.

Comment: The "single letter" convention is only true when there's only one type parameter in .NET, btw - when there are two, you end up with things like Dictionary<TKey, TValue>. Unfortunately I don't know enough about Haskell to really answer your question.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Sometimes you see <T, U> and so forth. I know MS provides a more detailed bit of advice on the subject too ... but it's not all that central to the main question.

Comment: Regardless of MS' advide I'd rather use a generic type with <TKey, TValue> than <T, U>. Live's hard enough as it is. @Charlie: perhaps you could edit your question and remove our nitpicking drivel?

Comment: I started to, but I can't bring myself to think of either of your comments as drivel.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's one difference to keep in mind:

C# has subtyping, but Haskell does not, which means, for one thing, that you *know* more things by simply looking at a Haskell type.

```
id :: a -> a
```

This Haskell function takes a value of a type and returns that same value of that same type.
If you give it a `Bool`, it will return a `Bool`. Give it a `Int`, it will return a `Int`. Give it a `Person`, it will return a `Person`.

In C#, you can't be so sure. This is that 'function' in C#:

```
public T Id<T>(T x);
```

Now, because of subtyping you could call it like so:

```
var pers = Id<Person>(new Student());
```

While `pers` is of type `Person`, the argument to the `Id` function is not. In fact `pers` might have a more specific type than just `Person`. `Person` could even be an abstract type, guaranteeing that `pers` will have a more specific type.

As you can see, even with a function as simple as `id` the .NET type system already allows for a lot more than the stricter type system from `Haskell`. While that might be useful to do some programming work, it also makes it harder to reason about a program by just looking a the types of things (which is a joy to do in Haskell).

---

And a second thing, there is *ad hoc* polymorphism (aka overloading) in Haskell, via a mechanism known as 'type classes'.

```
equals :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

This function checks if two values are equal. But not just any two values, just the values that have instances for the `Eq` class. This is sort of like constraints on type parameters in C#:

```
public bool Equals<T>(T x, T y) where T : IComparable
```

There is a difference, however. For one thing, the subtyping: you could instantiate it with `Person` and call it with `Student` and `Teacher`.

But there is also a difference in what this compiles to. The C# code compiles to almost exactly what its type says. The type checker makes sure the arguments implement the proper interface, and than you're good.

Whereas the Haskell code complies to something like this:

```
equals :: EqDict -> a -> a -> Bool
```

The function gets an *extra argument*, a dictionary of all the functions it needs to do the `Eq` things. Here's how you could use this function, and what it compiles to:

```
b1 = equals 2 4          --> b1 = equals intEqFunctions 2 4
b2 = equals True False   --> b2 = equals boolEqFunctions True False
```

This also shows what makes subtyping such a pain, imagine if this where possible.

```
b3 = equals someStudent someTeacher
     --> b3 = equals personEqFunctions someStudent someTeacher
```

How is the `personEqFunctions` dictionary supposed to figure out if a `Student` is equal to a `Teacher`? They don't even have the same fields.

In short, while Haskell type constraints at first sight might look like .NET type constraints, they are implemented completely differently and compile to two really different things.

Comment: Excellent. Here's one high-level conclusion I take from your post: You can reason a lot about a Haskell program by just looking at the type signatures. And that is key to some of Haskell's benefits. Do you feel the benefits of that outweigh benefits of subclassing?

Comment: Oh, I don't think I've ever missed subclassing. While you don't have subtyping, you do have encapsulation. So you can implement a `Stack` on top of a `List` by having it as a field, instead of subclassing it (which is a horrible way to implement a `Stack`, even in C#).

Comment: Also, if you need a 'is-a' relation (like `Student` is a `Person`), you can use type classes for that. Since class definitions can contain default implementations, its sort of like C# interfaces, but with code in them (a rumored feature of some newer version of .Net).

Comment: You might be thinking of the fact that extension methods can be "hung off of" interfaces in C#3.0. The effect is something like interfaces that have implementation in them, sort of. Or there may be some future feature planned as well ... wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: I don't think extension methods are as powerful. For one thing, you can't override them in the implementing class (what you can do with virtual abstract methods in an abstract super class). Also, you would effectively have empty interfaces with a whole bunch of extension methods, that seems weird.

Comment: In Haskell you can declare an existing type is an instance of a new class: "instance MyClass Int".  Can you do something similar in C#?

Comment: In C#, you can only implement an interface when defining a type. You can split up a type (class) definition across multiple files (called partial classes). This can be very useful, especially for code generation, but its less powerful than implementing an interface for an existing type.

Comment: @Paul: Interesting. 2 questions: 1) is MyClass just an "alias" for Int, or is there more to it? 2) The phrase "is an instance of a new class" makes me think that all types in Haskell are instances of a "Class" class (very much like Ruby). Is that true?

Comment: @Charlie: A type class in Haskell is comparable to an interface in C#. Saying that your data type is an instance of a class means that the functions defined for that class can be called on your data type. Writing "instance MyClass Int" in Haskell is like writing "class Int32 : IMyInterface {}" in C#

Answer (score 18):

We can do other things with Haskell type classes too now. Googling for "generics" in Haskell opens up a whole field of higher-rank polymorphic generic programming, beyond the standard parametric polymorphism most people think of as "generics".

For example, GHC recently gained type families, enabling all sorts of interesting type programming capabilities. A very simple example is per-type data representation decisions for arbitrary polymorphic containers.

I can make a class for say, lists,

```
class Listy a where

    data List a 
             -- this allows me to write a specific representation type for every particular 'a' I might store!

    empty   :: List a
    cons    :: a -> List a -> List a
    head    :: List a -> a
    tail    :: List a -> List a
```

I can write functions that operate on anything that instantiates List:

```
map :: (Listy a, Listy b) => (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
map f as = go as
  where
    go xs
        | null xs   = empty
        | otherwise = f (head xs) `cons` go (tail xs)
```

And yet we've never given a particular representation type.

Now that is a class for a generic list. I can give particular cunning representations based on the element types. So e.g. for lists of Int, I might use an array:

```
instance Listy Int where

data List Int = UArray Int Int

...
```

So you can start doing some pretty powerful generic programming.

Comment: Of course, next to type families there are all sorts of "generic programming" libraries in Haskell to do data type generic programming. Just to be clear to the original questioner: While this is also called "generics", this has very little to do with C# generics.

Answer (score 7):

Another big difference is that C# generics don't allow abstraction over type constructors (i.e. kinds other than *) while Haskell does. Try translating the following datatype into a C# class:

```
newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }
```

Comment: I think my head just exploded. Can you show some example code using Fix?

Comment: Hi Jared, consider "data Expr r = Num Int | Add r r" and then try to come up with some values of type "Fix Expr". Playing with this should give you a feeling about what's going on!

Answer (score 6):

To follow up on the, "you can get into big trouble thinking that a concept you're familiar with from one language is the same in another language [to which you're new]" part of this question:

Here's the key difference (from, say, Ruby) you need to understand when you use Haskell type classes. Given a function such as

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add x y = x + y
```

This does *not* mean that `x` and `y` are both any types of class `Num`. It means that `x` and `y` are of the exact same type, which type is of class `Num`. "Well, of course you say; *a* is the same thing as *a*." Which I say too, but it took me many months to stop thinking that if `x` was an `Int` and `y` was an `Integer`, it would be just like adding a `Fixnum` and `Bignum` in Ruby. Rather:

```
*Main> add (2::Int) (3::Integer)

<interactive>:1:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' against inferred type `Integer'
    In the second argument of `add', namely `(3 :: Integer)'
    In the expression: add (2 :: Int) (3 :: Integer)
    In the definition of `it': it = add (2 :: Int) (3 :: Integer)
```

In other words, subclassing (though both those `Num` instances are of course also instances of `Eq`) and duck typing are gone, baby.

This sounds pretty simple and obvious, but it takes quite some time to train yourself to understand this instinctively, rather than just intellectually, at least if you've come from years of Java and Ruby.

And no, once I got the hang of this, I don't miss subclassing a bit. (Well, maybe a little now and then, but I've gained much more than I've lost. And when I really miss it, I can try to misuse existential types.)